How to display content this way after running (org-sort)?
Hi I created a function using (org-sort) to prompt me to sort child / sub headings (the same as choosing the menu item Org > Edit structure > Sort Region/Children) of a parent heading and this works well.
After (org-sort) is run though, all the levels of child headings are shown as well as their contents - ie the same as pressing Shift-Tab > SHOW ALL
I would like after the sort that all levels of subheadings are shown, but not their contents - ie the same as pressing Shift-Tab > CONTENTS
And for the life of me I have not been able to do that. I have tried:
;; (org-sort-entries t) does not work
;; (org-sort-entries nil) does not work
;; (org-content 2) This shows 1st level children BUT removes blank lines between headings
;; (org-show-children) Does not work
;; (org-show-children 0) also does not do what I want
;; (org-show-children 1) ;; Show 1st level subheadings BUT with their contents expanded which I do not want
;; (org-show-branches) Does not work
;; (outline-show-children) also does not do what I want
;; (org-cycle)   ;; org-cycle is the command for pressing the Tab key which is what I want
;; (org-cycle)   ;; The first time it is run, it closes the heading, so run it again and you get what you want which is subheadings shown
;; BUT for the 2nd time it runs it does not work
What command / function could I use to display the content this way after a sort command?
Or should I be using a command other than (org-sort)?
